# Riak on top of LevelDB

Tags: riak, distributed-system, key-value-store, leveldb

I am planning to run Riak on top of LevelDB. I have downloaded both the packages for Riak and LevelDB separately. I am not sure how to link Riak with LevelDB - I didnt find any installation documents to run Riak on LevelDB. 
I am not sure if I have to do these two installations separately or there is a way where I can work install one package which has Riak and customized leveldb for the same. 
I am new to this and learning, so any suggestions will really help here.

Also, if I am heading into the right direction by installing Riak and LevelDB separately - how should I link them?

Answer (score 3):

As per the [Riak leveldb documentation](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/advanced/backends/leveldb/):

> Riak ships with eLevelDB included within the distribution, so there is no separate installation required. However, Riak is configured to use the Bitcask storage engine by default. To switch to eLevelDB, set the storage_backend variable in riak.conf to leveldb.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to download LevelDB separately from Riak. Riak packages include the relevant LevelDB build for the specific OS. Note, Basho has enhanced [LevelDB](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/setup/planning/backend/leveldb/), so original LevelDB from Google will probably not work with Riak.

Riak KV includes both Bitcask and LevelDB, while Riak TS has only LevelDB.
To use Riak with LevelDB, edit *riak.conf* on each node as described [here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/latest/configuring/reference/#storage-backend).
Additional LevelDB parameters are described [here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/configuring/backend/#leveldb).